# How do I write an extension function to return the average of a custom type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, average

This is probably very simple, but my attempts (guided by Intellisense and MSDN) have all been off the mark.

If I have a class which contains 3 double, how can I get the average of a list of these?

```
class DataPoint
{
    public int time;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
    // Constructor omitted
}

class Main
{
    List<DataPoint> points = new List<DataPoint>();
    // Populate list
    DataPoint averagePoint = points.Average(someMagicHere);
}
```

I want `averagePoint` to contain `time`, `x`, `y` & `z` values that are the average of these properties of the elements that make up the list. How do I do this? The bit I'm struggling with is (I think) `someMagicHere`, but I could be using completely the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: Your variable names should never start with an upper-case.  That style is reserved for types and methods.  i.e.  `points` and not `Points`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, was being sloppy in writing the question. Will correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static class DataPointExtensions
{
 public static DataPoint Average (this IEnumerable<DataPoint> points)
 {
   int sumX=0, sumY=0, sumZ=0, count=0;
   foreach (var pt in points)
   {
      sumX += pt.X;
      sumY += pt.Y;
      sumZ += pt.Z;
      count++;
   }
   // also calc average time?
   if (count == 0)
     return new DataPoint ();
   return new DataPoint {X=sumX/count,Y=sumY/count,Z=sumZ/count};
 }
}
```

Comment: Ah, seems the function needs to be static too. Working now - thanks!

Comment: Just to make a point, the DataPointExtensions class has to be in the same namespace as DataPoint, or else you have to use the using directive.

Comment: @Gleno, that's not how namespaces work. The extension class has to be visible just like any other class you want to use without using the full name (incl. namespace). It's possible that the class is in the same namespace as `DataPoint` and you won't be able to use it, because you don't have the correct `using`. OTOH, if you are in the namespace `Foo.Bar` and the class in is `Foo`, you can use it even without `using`.

Comment: @agent-j, I think the type of sumX, sumY, sumZ should be "long".  Otherwise you risk Overflow exception.

Answer (score 6):

The question is not entirely clear, but it sounds like what you want is a new point P where P.X is the average of all the X coordinates of the points in the list, and so on, yes?

The general way to solve a problem like this is to break it down:

First transform the list of points into four lists of integers.

```
var times = from p in points select p.Time;
var xs = from p in points select p.X;
... and so on ..
```

Or, if you prefer this notation:

```
var times = points.Select(p=>p.Time);
```

Now you can average those:

```
double averageTime = times.Average();
double averageX = xs.Average();
... and so on ...
```

and now you have your four values -- as doubles -- that you can use to construct the average point. Of course you'll have to convert the doubles to integers, using whatever rounding you prefer.

However, there is a special version of "Average" which combines the Select and the Average into one operation. You can just say

```
double averageTime = points.Average(p=>p.Time);
```

and do it in one step for both the projection and the average.

The down side of this approach, as some have noted, is that the sequence is enumerated four times. Which is probably not a big deal, since it is an in-memory list, but might be more of a big deal if it were an expensive database query.

Another approach would be to define the addition operator on your DataPoint class (if in general it makes sense to sum two points, which it might not). Once you have an addition operator, making the sum of all the points is straightforward.

Whether you define an addition operator or not, you can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) to compute the sum of all the Points, and then divide the four fields of the sum by the number of points.

```
DataPoint sum = points.Aggregate(
    new DataPoint(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    (agg, point)=> new DataPoint(agg.time + point.time, agg.x + point.x, ... ));
```

or, if you have the operator, simply:

```
DataPoint sum = points.Aggregate(
    new DataPoint(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    (agg, point)=> agg + point);
```

And now you have the sum, so computing the average is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would seem that you need to take average of each projection in turn

```
DataPoint averagePoint = new DataPoint{ 
            X = (int)Points.Average(p => X), 
            Y = (int)Points.Average(p => P.Y), 
            Z = (int)Points.Average(p => p.Z), 
            time = (int)Points.Average(p => p.time)
            };
```

I cast to int, because your types are `int`, although they probably should be `double`, or converted to your integer lattice more intelligently.

Another way is using running averages. It's slower than Lamperts, and assumes that the backing datatype for the `DataPoint` is double. But if the set of Points is HUGE, and points are ordered randomly it has a nice Monte-Carlo convergence. It also enumarates the `List` only once.:

```
var averagePoint = Points.First();
foreach(var point in Points.Skip(1).Select((p,i) => new{ Point = p, Index = i})){
          averagePoint.X = (point.Index * averagePoint.X + p.Point.X)/(point.Index + 1);
          averagePoint.Y = (point.Index * averagePoint.Y + p.Point.Y)/(point.Index + 1);
          averagePoint.Z = (point.Index * averagePoint.Z + p.Point.Z)/(point.Index + 1);
}
```

Comment: The main downside to this approach is that it enumerates the entire collection four times (once for each parameter being averaged.)

Comment: It's only slower if speed is important. :)